# GET request with nested query REST API

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, rest, mongoose

From my MongoDB database, I am querying data. For this, in my backend, I am getting the data by this,

```
const products = await Product.find({
    'backCamera.sensor.megaPixels': { $gte: 8 }
  })
```

How I can send a GET request from the front end to meet this query?

> I've tried this way but didn't work

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/products?backCamera.sensor.megaPixels[gte]=8')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Then tried to use the query params in backend but didn't work out.

Comment: what is the 12 for? And can you show the code of you console logging the request params in the backend?

Comment: sorry, edited now.. you can recheck

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to match the query from the URL to the query in the backend, nor to send it directly. Hence, you do not need a reason to do something like `api/v1/products?backCamera.sensor.megaPixels[gte]=8`. In this case, I would pass something like `api/v1/products?backCamSensorMinPx=8`, and then I would extract the data on the backend from req.query and validate it. It will solve some security issues (in case you were using the SQL), and it will follow some good practices of separating the backend core logic, and the database implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire thing dynamically with the url, meaning that the parameter `backCamera.sensor.megaPixels` is dynamically, you can go for it like this:

```js
// Frontend
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/products?product=backCamera.sensor.megaPixels&minimum=8')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));

// Backend
// Retrieve the params product and minimum from the Url
const products = await Product.find({
    [product]: { $gte: minimum }
  })
```